# Loop Over every Nth item in Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

can anyone advise how to loop over every Nth item in a dictionary?
Essentially I have  a dictionary of dataframes and I want to be able to create a new dictionary based on every 3rd dataframe item (including the first) based on index positioning of the original. Once I have this I would like to concatenate the dataframes together.

So for example if I have 12 dataframes ,  I would like the new dataframe to contain the first,fourth,seventh,tenth etc..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use a dictionary and not a list if you want to index by position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask it a bit strange. Anyway, you have two main options.

- convert your dictionary values to list and slice that:

```
out = pd.concat(list(dfs.values())[::3])
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  x  x  x
0  x  x  x
0  x  x  x
0  x  x  x
```

- slice your dictionary keys and generate a subdictionary:

```
out = pd.concat({k: dfs[k] for k in list(dfs)[::3]})
```

output:

```
        a  b  c
df1  0  x  x  x
df4  0  x  x  x
df7  0  x  x  x
df10 0  x  x  x
```

Used input:

```
dfs = {f'df{i+1}': pd.DataFrame([['x']*3], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) for i in range(12)}
```

Comment: thank you for the insight here, really useful! The reason is because I  was using an API to pull data from various report 'sets'. The output of each report, in this case 3 reports per instance, is stored in a dictionary of dataframes , where every report repeats sequentially in the same "spacing", so when the download is for large groups this helps me collate, thanks again for the insight!

Comment: So this worked as you wanted with your real dataset? Which approach did you use?

Comment: I used the second option:
slice your dictionary keys and generate a subdictionary:
out = pd.concat({k: dfs[k] for k in list(dfs)[::3]})
Thanks again Mozway!

Answer (score 1):

if the `dict` is required, you may use `tuple` of `dict` keys:

```
custom_dict = {
    'first': 1,
    'second': 2,
    'third': 3,
    'fourth': 4,
    'fifth': 5,
    'sixth': 6,
    'seventh': 7,
    'eighth': 8,
    'nineth': 9,
    'tenth': 10,
    'eleventh': 11,
    'twelveth': 12,
}
for key in tuple(custom_dict)[::3]:
    print(custom_dict[key])
```

then, you may call `pandas.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        custom_dict[key]
        for key in tuple(custom_dict)[::3]
    ],
    # =========================================================================
    # axis=0 # To Append One DataFrame to Another Vertically
    # =========================================================================
    axis=1 # To Append One DataFrame to Another Horisontally
)
```

assuming `custom_dict[key]` returns `pandas.DataFrame`, not `int` as in my code above.